# Qlabel show images too slow its about file size?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I try to show video frames on QLabel and I use opencv videocaptue and use Qtimer for show frames in QLabel. But frames coming too slow, they coming about 5 seconds late.

Here is my class constructor:

```
        self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.record)
```

and here is my record function and call every seconds `self.timer.start(1000)` :

```
    def record(self):
        start = time.time()
        self.parent.timerLabel.setTimerText()
        ret, frame = self.vid.read()
        new = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.parent.setImageToLabel(new)
        end = time.time()
        print(end - start)
```

setImageToLabel function:

```
    def setImageToLabel(self, frame):
        if type(frame) == str:
            pixmap = QPixmap(QImage(frame))
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(320, 240)
            self.videoFrame.setPixmap(pixmap)
        else:
            height, width, channel = frame.shape
            self.videoFrame.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(QImage(frame.data, width, height, QImage.Format_RGB888)))
```

Here is process times for every seconds:

```
0.8245744705200195
0.004508256912231445
0.0037131309509277344
0.0024259090423583984
0.002048969268798828
0.0022318363189697266
```

Its not so high

I save frames and frame size 640x480px and file size is about 480kB
I think its about file size is there any option for decrese image quality ?

Comment: Ehm... `timeit.timeit()` does not return the current time, so you're not measuring the elapsed time (in fact, it is returning negative values, which wouldn't make a lot of sense). Try it again with `datetime.now` or QElapsedTimer.

Comment: sorry I changed it with time and result not change a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Its about frame size I set `cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` and `cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT` before frame read and its work.

```
    def record(self):
        start = time.time()
        self.parent.timerLabel.setTimerText()
        self.vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)
        self.vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240)
        ret, frame = self.vid.read()
        new = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.parent.setImageToLabel(new)
        end = time.time()
        print(end - start)
```

after that I scaled from QPixmap and show my screen.

```
    def setImageToLabel(self, frame):
        if type(frame) == str:
            pixmap = QPixmap(QImage(frame))
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(1000, 600)
            self.videoFrame.setPixmap(pixmap)
        else:
            height, width, channel= frame.shape
            pixmap = QPixmap(QImage(frame.data, width, height, QImage.Format_RGB888))
            pixmap = pixmap.scaled(1000, 600)
            self.videoFrame.setPixmap(pixmap)
```